# How to Limit End Date Based on Selection in a Form

Tags: php, jquery, web

I'm working on a web form that includes a "Type of labor contract" selection, and I want to limit the "Effective Period End Date" based on the user's selection. Specifically, I'd like to ensure that if a user selects "Contract Limited time 120 days" from the dropdown, the "Effective Period End Date" cannot go beyond 120 days from the "Effective Period Start Date."

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateMaxEndDate() {
    var selectedOption = $('.type_of_labour').val();
    if (selectedOption === "2") {
      var startDate = new Date($('.effective_period_start_date').val());
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 120);
      var formattedMaxEndDate = startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
      $('.effective_period_end_date').attr('max', formattedMaxEndDate);
    }
  }

  // Initialize the max end date when the page loads
  updateMaxEndDate();

  // When the type of labor changes, update the max end date
  $('.type_of_labour').change(function() {
    updateMaxEndDate();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label for="inputSelectCountry" class="form-label">Type of labor contract</label>
  <select class="form-select type_of_labour" name="type_of_labour" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option value="1">Contract Limited time pay by wage</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Contract Limited time 120 days</option>
    <option value="3">Contract Limited time not over 2 years</option>
    <option value="4">Permanant</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Effective Period Start date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control effective_period_start_date" name="effective_period_start_date" value="2023-01-01" {{ $disabledfield }}>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Effective Period End date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control effective_period_end_date" name="effective_period_end_date" value="2023-04-01" {{ $disabledfield }}>
  </div>
</div>
```

Despite trying this code, I'm not seeing the expected behavior when I select "Contract Limited time 120 days." The end date does not seem to be limited to 120 days from the start date.

Comment: Can you replace the PHP code with actual option values in the snippet, so we can run it?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with PHP, since you're coding this on the front-end in JS.

Comment: @<select class="form-select type_of_labour" name="type_of_labour" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option value="1">Contract Limited time pay by wage</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Contract Limited time 120 days</option>
    <option value="3">Contract Limited time not over 2 years</option>
    <option value="4">Permanant</option>
</select>

Comment: this is my array from where i am getting my values $typeoflabour =[
 1 => 'Contract Limited time pay by wage',
 2 => 'Contract Limited time 120 days',
 3 => 'Contract Limited time not over 2 years',
 4 => 'Permanant'
];

Comment: Don't put it in a comment, edit the question.

Comment: i try to edit the question but it StackOverflow gives me error

Comment: @Barmar done with changes

Comment: it seems to work as desired. When I select Jan 16 in the start date, the maximum of end date is set to Apr 15.

Comment: @yes but as my code i only want 120 changes on 2 value of dropdown but the 120 days conditions apply on other dropdown aswell which I didn't want

Comment: You're using a class name, so it applies to all elements with that class. If you want a specific dropdown, use an ID instead of class. Or use DOM navigation methods to find a related dropdown.

Comment: After using id it stop working on any dropdown

Comment: Your inputs don't currently have an ID. Did you add it? Did you make sure you used a different ID for each of them?

Comment: If you're repeating this HTML and want each start date to update the corresponding end date, you want to use the DOM navigation method, relative to `$(this)`.